# Page contains multiple canonical issues

Tags: seo

i am using ISS SEO toolkit to analyze our website. Form that i got 450 canonical issues. all the errors in the same format as follows:

The page with URL "http://dynamicsexchange.com/images/Logoscroll/Images/511201091716pm_a.jpg" can also be accessed by using URL "http://www.dynamicsexchange.com/images/Logoscroll/Images/511201091716pm_a.jpg".Search engines identify unique pages by using URLs.  When a single page can be accessed by using any one of multiple URLs, a search engine assumes that there are multiple unique pages. Use a single URL to reference a page to prevent dilution of page relevance. You can prevent dilution by following a standard URL format.
Please help me to solve these problems with examples. and i am using masterpage concept.

i am using IIS web server please give me the solution to set the 301 redirect (i am using master page concept) with example

Answer (score 0):

Choose whether you want your visitors to use http://dynamicsexchange.com or http://www.dynamicsexchange.com. Then set up a 301 redirect to redirect any traffic from the one you don't want to the one you do want.

That way any traffic which accidentally links to the wrong one will be redirected to the right one. Search engines will then record all links to the right one, and so your page rank won't be diluted.

How to set up the 301 redirect will depend on what your web server is.